# Error adding two numbers

Tags: ios, swift

I have written piece of code to add two numbers. But I get this error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'int', Use of unresolved identifier
>   'y', Expected ',' separator.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var Num1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Num2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Total: UITextField!

     // MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func Submit(sender: AnyObject) {

        int x = ([Num1.text intValue]);
        int y = ([Num2.text intValue]);
        [Total setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", x + y]];
        // You may also need to check if your string data is a valid number
        //int result = [Num1.text, intValue] + [Num2.text, intValue];
      //  Total.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result];
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner, please help to solve this problem.

Comment: It seems that you just pasted some Objective-C code into a Swift file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize variables before using it ,

```
   var x:Int = Num1.text.toInt()
   var y:Int = Num2.text.toInt()
```

And you used objective-c codes for swift file

Comment: I initialized variables as you mentioned. Issues solved but while debugging got "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason : '[<addTwoNum.ViewController 0x7fe442ca0970> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Submit.'"

Comment: Mean while, got something error in AppDelegate.swift. Error : class AppDelegate : UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { (Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT.    and 0_pthread_kill

Comment: addTwoNum is name of project.

Comment: Check Whether all the IBOutlets Correctly connected to view controller , this error may show up because of you didn't correctly connect UITextField. Check again